# how to retrieve closest hidden field by class name in jquery?

Tags: jquery

how can i retrieve closest hidden field value of a span in jquery,
when i have this HTML tags on my page?

```
 <div>
    <div class="div1">
        <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" class="temp_parent" value="xxx" />
        <div>
            <span class="a123" onclick="findparentHiddenFiels()">click me1</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div2">
        <input id="Hidden2" type="hidden" class="temp_parent" value="yyy" />
        <div>
            <span class="a123" onclick="findparentHiddenFiels()">click me1</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this not works:

```
var hidenval = $(this).closest('input[class^="temp_parent"]').val();
```

Comment: `this` is window, not the element that was clicked.

Comment: don't inline handlers

Comment: @KevinB ,has right $(this) is window but if use in $('.a123').on("click", function (event) {.... all answers works fine,thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get rid of the inline event handler JS. Then use:

```
$('span.a123').click(function(){         
    var hidenval = $(this).closest('div').siblings('input:hidden').val();
});
```

Comment: If he gets rid of the inline event handler assignment then nothing will happen when he clicks the spans.

Comment: @j08691 i think you missed the `.click(function(){...` part.

Comment: Works great: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nE3pF/. Make sure you put the jQuery code in a document ready call, or at the end of your page.

Answer (score 1):

```
<span class="a123" onclick="findparentHiddenFiels(this)">click me1</span>

function findparentHiddenFiels(el){
    var $span = $(el);
    var $hidden = $span.parent().prev()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var hidenval = $(this).closest('div[class^="div"]').find('input.temp_parent').val();
```

or

```
var hidenval = $(this).parent().prev('input.temp_parent').val();
```

or

```
$('span.a123').click(function(){         
    var hidenval = $(this).parent().prev().val();
});
```

Reference

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: just use `parent()`, no need to use slow selectors.
but anyway `this` is not the `span`

Comment: `$(window).parent()` will likely not return any elements.